# How to add a listener to an accordion in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, listener

I am trying to code a program in which you can navigate through tab and then in the Tab you have several TitledPane in which you have some functionnalities.
For some of them, there fields to fill. I want the user to be asked if he wanted to save what he wrote in the fields when he changes of TitledPane or Tabs.

That is why, I want to add listeners on the method "getExpandedPane" of the accordion I created. So that I know which TitledPane is active in the moment.

Maybe you know how to do or maybe another solution...

Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Accordion?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxclinic.MainViewController">
   <center>
      <TabPane fx:id="tabPaneFunctions" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="374.0" prefWidth="800.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" tabMaxHeight="150.0" tabMinHeight="10.0" tabMinWidth="150.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <tabs>
            <Tab fx:id="appointmen" text="Appointments">
               <content>
                  <Accordion fx:id="appointmentsAccordion" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="78.0" prefWidth="800.0">
                     <panes>
                        <TitledPane fx:id="addAppointment" animated="false" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Add an appointment">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                           </content>
                        </TitledPane>
                        <TitledPane fx:id="deletePatient" animated="false" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Delete patient">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                           </content>
                        </TitledPane>
                        <TitledPane fx:id="searchPatient" animated="false" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Search for patient informations">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                           </content>
                        </TitledPane>
                     </panes>
                  </Accordion>
               </content>
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="50.0" fitWidth="50.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../img/appointment.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Tab>
            <Tab text="Doctors">
               <content>
                  <Accordion fx:id="doctorsAccordion" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="78.0" prefWidth="800.0">
                     <panes>
                        <TitledPane fx:id="listDoctors" animated="false" text="Show the list of doctors">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                           </content>
                        </TitledPane>
                        <TitledPane fx:id="addDoctor" animated="false" text="Add a doctor">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                           </content>
                        </TitledPane>
                        <TitledPane fx:id="deleteDoctor" animated="false" text="Delete a doctor">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                           </content>
                        </TitledPane>
                     </panes>
                  </Accordion>
               </content>
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="50.0" fitWidth="50.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../img/doctor.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Tab>
            <Tab text="Patients">
               <content>
                  <Accordion fx:id="patientsAccordion" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="78.0" prefWidth="800.0">
                     <panes>
                        <TitledPane fx:id="addPatient" animated="false" text="Add a patient">
                           <content>
                              <GridPane>
                                <columnConstraints>
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                </columnConstraints>
                                <rowConstraints>
                                    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                </rowConstraints>
                                 <children>
                                    <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                                    <Label text="Identification number" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                                    <Label text="First name" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                                    <Label text="Surname" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                                    <Label text="Phone Number" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                                    <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                                    <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                                    <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                                    <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.rowSpan="2" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                                       <children>
                                          <ImageView fitHeight="117.0" fitWidth="112.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                             <image>
                                                <Image url="@../img/addportrait_patient.png" />
                                             </image>
                                          </ImageView>
                                          <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="113.0" text="Photo" textAlignment="CENTER" />
                                       </children>
                                    </VBox>
                                    <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="6" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                                       <children>
                                          <Button alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="59.0" text="Clean">
                                             <HBox.margin>
                                                <Insets />
                                             </HBox.margin>
                                          </Button>
                                          <Button alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" defaultButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Save">
                                             <HBox.margin>
                                                <Insets left="20.0" />
                                             </HBox.margin>
                                          </Button>
                                       </children>
                                    </HBox>
                                 </children>
                                 <padding>
                                    <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                                 </padding>
                              </GridPane>
                           </content>
                        </TitledPane>
                        <TitledPane fx:id="deletePatient" animated="false" text="Delete patient">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                           </content>
                        </TitledPane>
                        <TitledPane fx:id="searchPatient" animated="false" text="Search for patient informations">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                           </content>
                        </TitledPane>
                     </panes>
                  </Accordion>
               </content>
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="50.0" fitWidth="50.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../img/patient.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Tab>
         </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </center>
   <top>
      <Text fx:id="clinicName" fill="#008dff" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" textAlignment="CENTER" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: java doc exists for a reason ... ;) Please read it ..

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Just add the listener to the property inside your controller. Or are you asking how to add a listener to that property from FXML?

Comment: @Jerem: Please [edit] your question to include further details or add a [mcve], rather than posting a comment.

Comment: (1) You need to add the listener to the [`expandedPane`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Accordion.html#expandedPaneProperty()) _property_. The `getExpandedPane()` method returns the _value_ of said property. (2) The `expandedPane` property holds `TitledPane`s, not `Tab`s, so you need to use a `ChangeListener<TitledPane>`. (3) If you're still stuck, please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue (as trashgod already mentioned).